# CNContactStore execute fails

Tags: swift, macos, contacts-framework

I am working out how to use the Contacts framework, however some fairly simple code to create a contact is failing with an unexpected result. This is my code:

```
    let Store = CNContactStore()
    Store.requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler:{ success, error in
        if success {
            let Contact = CNMutableContact()
            Contact.givenName = "Dave"
            Contact.familyName = "Nottage"
            let SaveRequest = CNSaveRequest()
            SaveRequest.add(Contact, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
            do {
                try Store.execute(SaveRequest)
                print("Success")
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            print("No access")
        }
    })
```

..and this is the result:

```
2019-02-22 10:30:56.050344+1030 ContactsTest[30329:25254955] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
2019-02-22 10:30:57.973724+1030 ContactsTest[30329:25254955] Could not get real path for Address Book lock folder: open() for F_GETPATH failed.
2019-02-22 10:30:57.973954+1030 ContactsTest[30329:25254955] Unable to open file lock: <ABProcessSharedLock: 0x600001752ac0: name=(null), lockFilePath=(null), localLock=<NSRecursiveLock: 0x600002914a80>{recursion count = 0, name = nil}, fileDescriptor=-1> Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=14 "Bad address" UserInfo={ABFileDescriptor=-1}
The operation couldn’t be completed. (Foundation._GenericObjCError error 0.)
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Edit: Note also that this is being compiled for macOS 10.14 SDK, and is running on macOS 10.14.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to check the Contacts checkbox of App Data in the App Sandbox section in Capabilities and turn on the switch for App Sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you added key **NSContactsUsageDescription** in **Info.plist**.

Please refer to [link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts).

> **Important**
>
> An iOS app linked on or after iOS 10.0 must include in its Info.plist
>   file the usage description keys for the types of data it needs to
>   access or it will crash. To access Contacts data specifically, it must
>   include NSContactsUsageDescription.